# Indefinite trignometric integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I tried $u$-substitution and $uv$-substitution, can't seem to figure this out... any help would be appreciated!

Question:

> $$\int\frac{x}{\cos(x)}\,dx$$

Thanks!!!

Comment: I tried...it's gonna get me something really nasty though... :(

Comment: Are you sure that you need  this integral ? It is a **monster** (at least to me).

Comment: Hahah my professor put it on the extra practice exercise for the midterm tomorrow. :(

Comment: The solution isn't elementary: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate(x%2F(cos(x)). But with $\cos^2$ is elementary.

Answer (score 3):

As I already commented $$I=\int\frac{x}{\cos(x)}\,dx$$ looks to be a monster.

What I am ready to bet is that the problem is $$J=\int\frac{x}{\cos^2(x)}\,dx$$ which is a totally different story.

Integrating by parts $u=x$, $v'=\frac{dx}{\cos^2(x)}$, $u'=dx$, $v=\tan(x)$ give $$J=x \tan(x)-\int \tan(x)\,dx=x \tan(x)-\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\,dx=x \tan(x)+\log(\cos(x))+C$$

Looking deeper $$K_n=\int\frac{x}{\cos^n(x)}\,dx$$ is a monster if $n$ is odd and "quite" simple if $n$ is even.

Comment: Oh goodness :(Thanks a lot though, Claude!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> *I tried u-substitution and uv-substitution, can't seem to figure this out...*

No wonder you can't, since it is not expressible in terms of elementary functions. See [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information. If it were, then the definite integral $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\dfrac{\tfrac\pi2-x}{\cos x}~dx=2G$ would not require the presence of [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant) in its expression.